# Rabbit MQ -Message Order Priority Consumption

Tags: asynchronous, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

Using Rabbit MQ
Is there a way ,I can ensure all messages of Type A are consumed before messages of Type B.

Eg: if I have a pool of Product and Order messages,
I want to make sure all Product messages are consumed before Order messages ?
As Order belongs to a specific Product.So Order cannot exist without a Product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with two queues and two listeners, but that would be tricky; you would have to hold up the Order listener when a Product is missing and wait for it to arrive.

You could do it with a single queue and single concurrency as long as the producer always sends the Product before the Order.